# Issues with entity addon in spring roo 1.2.4

Tags: spring-roo

I just updated to roo 1.2.4 and when trying to use the entity command I get the following:

```
backoffice roo> entity
Command 'entity' not found (for assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
Located add-on that may offer this command
1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------

01 Y Y 1.2.0.M1 Support for the creation and management of domain entities.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
backoffice roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01
Target resource(s):
-------------------
   Spring Roo - Addon - Entity (1.2.0.M1)

Required resource(s):
---------------------
   Spring Roo - Support (1.2.0.RELEASE)

Deploying...done.

backoffice roo> [org.apache.felix.bundlerepository [12]] Resolver: Start error -
 org.springframework.roo.addon.entity
org.apache.felix.log.LogException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve module org.springframework.roo.addon.entity
[83.0] because it is exposed to package 'org.springframework.roo.support.util' from modules org.springframework.roo.support [68.1] and org.springframework.roo.s
upport [68.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.springframework.roo.addon.entity [83.0]
    import: (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.util)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: package=org.springframework.roo.support.util  org.springframework.roo.support [68.1]

Chain 2:
  org.springframework.roo.addon.entity [83.0]
    import: (&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath.customdata)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: package=org.springframework.roo.classpath.customdata; uses:=org.springframework.roo.support.util
  org.springframework.roo.classpath [52.0]
    import: (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.util)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: package=org.springframework.roo.support.util  org.springframework.roo.support [68.0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3570)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:927)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ResolverImpl.deploy(ResolverImpl.java:630)
    at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ObrCommandImpl._deploy(ObrCommandImpl.java:395)
    at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ObrCommandImpl.deploy(ObrCommandImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ObrCommandImpl.execute(ObrCommandImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.felix.shell.impl.Activator$ShellServiceImpl.executeCommand(Activator.java:286)
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.FelixDelegator.perform(FelixDelegator.java:208)
    at org.springframework.roo.felix.FelixDelegator.obrStart(FelixDelegator.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy$1.callback(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:47)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProcessManager.doTransactionally(DefaultProcessManager.java:283)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProcessManager.execute(DefaultProcessManager.java:64)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.execute(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:44)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.AbstractShell.executeCommandImpl(AbstractShell.java:226)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:146)
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.installOrUpgradeAddOn(AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.java:478)
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.installAddon(AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.java:396)
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddODownloaded 100% of lookup
tallAddOn(AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.java:458)
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnCommands.installId(AddOnCommands.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nat
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy$1.callback(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:47)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProcessManager.doTransactionally(DefaultProcessManager.java:283)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProcessManager.execute(DefaultProcessManager.java:64)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.execute(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:44)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.AbstractShell.executeCommandImpl(AbstractShell.java:226)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:146)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.jline.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLineShell.java:421)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.jline.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.java:539)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Successfully installed add-on: Spring Roo - Addon - Entity [version: 1.2.0.M1]
[Hint] Please consider rating this add-on with the following command:
[Hint] addon feedback bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.addon.
entity --rating ... --comment "..."
backoffice roo> quit
```

After this, I can't start roo anymore. If I delete the cache directory, I can start it, but I end up in the same place.

More information, I just recently upgraded from 1.2.3. For the most part, my entities were created using DBRE. My pom.xml is using roo version 1.2.4.RELEASE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but it remains a likely stumbling block for new Roo users referring to (relatively) old Roo instructions, tutorials, etc.

A: The syntax has changed. The `entity` command is now the `entity jpa` command.

Sorry: In haste I missed the other question, which was well handled by mvivo. I would add my own opinion that the **bundle** directory is one that can--I'd say should--be deleted. Doing so may exact a toll in time lost to downloading. Bur if bad stuff has somehow been downloaded or downloads have somehow been corrupted on the local system, the new release, and subsequent **addon** commands will quickly restore the **bundle** directory to a consistent, up-to-date state. There don't appear to be within Roo redundant data structures that can get out of sync. Certainly I've not yet encountered any.

I've been doing Roo for only a week or two and helps such as these would have saved me plenty of late-night time. I will say, though, that Roo seems well behaved. I mean by that when I tried what seemed to me a reasonable fix things generally did get better. I have on occasion worked with the other kind of system--the one in which things get worse apparently not matter what you do. Roo's not like that. It's relatively simple and, as a result, inherently robust. I greatly admire the design insights behind Roo.

Answer (score 0):

To solve problems of Spring Roo doesn't starts. Delete all Spring Roo folders (cache and installation) try with a clean installation of 1.2.4 (or 1.2.5) version.

As already answered here: `entity` command is renamed to `entity jpa` (see [Spring Roo documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-persistence.html))